# Policy on answers containing spam

Tags: discussion

The following answer originally contained a spam link:

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/101444/42636

Unless there already is such a policy, I suggest that in the future answers containing spam should categorically be deleted. Regardless of how good the answer in itself may be, it is obviously made with ill intentions, and should not be tried to salvage by editing.

I further suggest the posters of such answers should be banned.

Comment: Of course there is already such a policy.  On all SE sites.

Comment: @Bianfable partially yes. My question does, however,  come with the twist of the question in question (lol) not being totally bogus, such that it could be edited by removing the spam portion. It is obvious that plain spam is to be flagged for deletion, but I'm seeking unison in the specific case of a "mixed" answer.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the approach you suggest.

The answer has been deleted by the system and the user has been banned.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! The best course for individuals is to **Flag** the post as **Spam** (or, Rude/Abusive, if that applies better), which accomplishes a couple of things:

- First, it highlights the post for moderator attention, so that we can delete it & address (i.e. ban) the author.
- Second, this flag applies a down-vote to the post, so it gets less attention.
- Third, enough Spam or Rude/Abusive flags will delete the post even without moderator action.

What individuals should ***not*** do: Don't edit the post to "fix" it:

- Doing so obscures the original problem with the post (the spam link, rude comments, whatever), making it harder for subsequent users without high-rep privileges to see the problem, which makes it less likely they'll **Flag** it as **Spam**.
- The original author can reject any such edits later, putting the bad content back up, where search engines can crawl it.
- The answer probably isn't really ***worth*** "fixing" anyway... experts don't tend to write good answers just to slip links or insults in.

If you see a post you're unsure about, you can always **Flag** it "in need of moderator intervention" and we'll take a look at it. You can do this without the down-vote that comes with a Spam flag, so there's no harm if the post is determined to be benign.

Your mods very much appreciate everybody who reports Spam and Rude/Abusive posts; we have a good community here, and when we need to pull out the broom & dustpan to clean something up, the faster we can do that, the better. So ***thank you***, all!

Comment: As for the *"experts don't tend to write good answers just to slip links or insults in"*: this problem will become more prominent with the availability of LLM services. Any trolling noob can produce at least somewhat convincing answers with tools such as ChatGPT.

Comment: @Jpe61  True, but I'd suggest that such answers aren't worth correcting either. When a flawlessly written answer has an obvious, wildly incorrect "hallucination" in it, flag it as low quality & note the problem in the remarks. We don't need to "improve" such answers, IMHO, but rather to zorch them.

Comment: That's my point exactly.